# Yet, another part ID question: Large blue dish

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone have an idea what the circled piece could be? Picture from [this Flickr gallery](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legoloverman/4233496737/).

[image]

I'm thinking it's circular so I've been scouring BrickLink for dishes and disks but have not been successful so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Set #4417- Aero Pod](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=4417-1)*.

[image]

1. Top.[image] Part #4767 - Blue
   Container, X-Pod Top Cap 9 x 9 x 1 1/3.
2. Middle. [image] Part #47674 -
   Trans-Yellow Container, X-Pod Barrel Section 10 x 10 x 3 1/3.
3. Bottom. [image] Part #47676 - Blue
   Container, X-Pod Bottom Cap 9 x 9 x 1.

Comment: to be exact is the one from:[4417-1: Aero Pod](https://brickset.com/sets/4417-1/Aero-Pod)

Comment: You guys are the best!  No wonder I couldn't find it, I've never even heard of these things.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Like you said Joost!